# Filling a TListBox with a column from a database query

Tags: delphi, mydac

I created a table in my database with **MYDAC** components and added data. How can i extract these values that in colums from this table?

i tried these but they didn't work;

```
 MyQuery1.Close;
 MyQuery1.SQL.Text :='SELECT * FROM uyeler ORDER BY site';
 Listbox1.Items.Add(MyQuery1.ParamByName('site').AsString);
 MyQuery1.Execute;
```

uyeler = table

site = colums

Editors Note: Based on comments made to accepted answer, this question is asking how to populate a `TListBox` with the data returned in a column of a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. You ask how to add column data to a `TListBox`, but your code sample shows something about `ParamByName`, which looks like you're trying to assign a `ListBox` value to a SQL parameter.

**Note**: Question clarified based on comment to this reply. The first code answers the question; I'll leave the second as an example for future readers because it's already written.

If you're trying to fill a `TListBox` from a database column, you need to run the query, and then loop through the data to add the column data to your `TListBox`. (You also shouldn't `SELECT *` when you're only going to use the `site` column; it means extra data is being sent from the database to the application when the data will never be used and will end up being thrown away.)

This should help you get started:

```
MyQuery1.Close;
MyQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT site FROM uyeler ORDER BY site';
try
  MyQuery1.Open;
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  while not MyQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(MyQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
    MyQuery1.Next;
  end;
finally
  MyQuery1.Close;
end;
```

If you're trying to do the second (populate a parameter with a value from a `TListBox`), this should help:

```
// to shorten typing of long lines
var
  Site: string;
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    MyQuery1.Close;
    MyQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    MyQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT Column1, Column2, site FROM uyeler');
    MyQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE site = :siteval ORDER BY site');
    Site := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
    MyQuery1.ParamByName('siteval').AsString := Site;
    MyQuery1.Open;
    try
      // Use the database rows here
    finally
      MyQuery1.Close;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Ankara, can you either edit your question (or post a comment to my answer) so future readers know which part answered your question? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved we need your help. I little know English.

Comment: @Ankara, you're welcome. Was it the first part of my answer that helped, or the second?

Comment: @Ankara, thank you. I edited your question (and my answer) to say that the first part is what you wanted. :-)